# Efficient Implementation of Dynamic Geofencing in React Native with Dynamic Locations and Radii

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation, android-geofence, geofence

I'm a backend developer, new to implementing geofencing in React Native. I'm working on an app that needs to display geofences around stores with dynamic radii, retrieved from an API. Here are my requirements and questions:

Rendering Geofences: I want to show geofences only for stores within a certain distance (x km) from the user's location. The radii for each store can be different and will come from an API.

Dynamic Updates: Geofences should appear on the user's phone when they are near the stores and disappear when they move away beyond a specific distance. I'm considering an "invalidate" strategy for geofences to optimize performance. Is this a good approach?

API Trigger: When a user enters a geofenced area, I want to trigger an API call with data related to that zone.

I'm open to suggestions and welcome feedback on my approach. If there's a better way to implement this or if my idea needs improvement, please let me know.

I've spoken with some developers who mentioned the need for a background process that updates data every few seconds. However, I'm concerned that this could negatively impact performance. Is this a valid concern?

I appreciate your guidance and any insights you can provide. Thank you!